# android jxlapi - getting IOexception on createworkbook

Tags: android

just some simple code...

```
public void writeExcel(String filePath, java.lang.Boolean exportExercise,
        java.lang.Boolean exportClass, java.lang.Boolean exportNotes, 
        java.lang.Boolean exportRecords) throws IOException, WriteException  {
    Cell cell;

WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(filePath)); 
    ...
    ...
```

and I'm getting an IOException. The filePath is valid, so what other reasons could  this snippet
be throwing an exception?

Comment: If you take the "throws" off the method and put in a try/catch block, what is the exact exception you're getting?  I suspect it's because Excel is already open, but I'd have to get more info from you.